# Getting 90 degree coordinate of 2 coordinates that you know

Tags: problem-solving, triangles

I have 2 coordinates and I need to find the third with a 90 degree angle. How could I do this?

[image]

```
A = 50.88259382849774,6.003988087177277
B = 50.88269282423443,6.0036662220954895
C = ?

C is 90 degrees

AB = 25m
```

Comment: By 'A is 45 degrees' do you mean that the line from A to C is on a 45-degree angle (with either the horizontal or vertical)?  (That's not quite the case in the diagram)

Comment: Yea but it's not supposed to be a rectangle its a triangle. So the corner C is 90 degrees and the other 2 are 45 degrees. I do have another question too actually. If you split a rectangle does it always have 2 corners of 45 degrees and one of 90 degrees?

Comment: As noted in an answer, if you split a rectangle it definitely does _not_ have two 45-degree corners.  What's the root problem you're trying to solve?  If you're trying to 'box out' a square, not necessarily aligned, with AB as the diagonal then that's straightforward, but if you're trying to find a specific rectangle with AB as diagonal then just having the diagonal isn't enough information.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use the converse of the Pythagorean theorem. Find $C$ so that $$(AB)^2=(AC)^2+(BC)^2.$$

Alternatively, you can use the fact that $C$ lies on the line $AC$ and $BC$.

**Edit**

Because there are two $45^{\circ}$ angles, the sides opposite of them will have length $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \cdot AB$. Say you find this length and call it $L$. Then in order to find the coordinates of $C$ you could do the following:
Let $C=(x,y).$ Then, by the distance formula,
 \begin{align*}
(50.88259382849774-x)^2&+(6.003988087177277-y)^2\\
&=(50.88269282423443-x)^2+(6.0036662220954895-y)^2\\
&=L^2
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm not very good at math to be honest. But if I would know the length from A to B, could I calculate the length from A to C and B to C? I am programming and I have been trying for a while to figure this formula out because I need it to make it work.

Comment: I editted my question. I know the degrees of A and B too.

Comment: Ah that simplifies it a lot...I'll update my answer

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out but it just doesn't work for me I can't solve it. I calculated L though it's 25 meters.

Comment: I was wrong about the 45 degrees it's not always true..

Answer (score 1):

Given three distinct points $A,B$, and $C,\ \angle ACB=90^\circ$ if and only if $C$ lies on the circle with diameter $\overline{AB}$. So, there are an infinite number of point that satisfy your initial requirements.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by `A is 45 degrees` and `B is 45 degrees`, since $A$ and $B$ are points, not angles. If you could clarify, then I could answer your question more specifically.

Comment: Well it's the corner of A and B. The rectangle is split into a triangle so it has one corner of 90 degrees (C) and the other two are 45 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

All right angled triangles do not have 45 degrees as one of them !

The differences in x or y you gave is so small compared to 25.

xa = 50.88259382849774; ya = 6.003988087177277
xb = 50.88269282423443; yb = 6.0036662220954895

Sqrt[(xa - xb)^2 + (ya - yb)^2] is only ~ 0.000336745 not near 25.

To find C you need to give in addition inclination of CB or CA or AB to the x- or y-axis, else your problem cannot be solved.

This is because your right angled triangle has freedom to rotate all around the origin.

Comment: Well these coordinates are real coordinates from google maps and you can calculate it using this site: http://boulter.com/gps/distance/?from=50.88259382849774%2C6.003988087177277&to=50.88269282423443%2C6.0036662220954895&units=k

Comment: @SinanSamet: Wow, where did you mention that these are for GPS , latitude,longitude of the Earth and so on?

Comment: I'm sorry didn't know how exactly to word it.